# Cygwin, Cassandra: Run nodetool with space in path

Tags: path, cassandra, cygwin, space, nodetool

Currently using Cassandra 2.1.9 in Windows 7.
I'm trying to use nodetool in Cygwin but getting below message:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/DataStax Community/apache-cassandra/bin
$ ./nodetool
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program
```

I tried to create alias for this directory, but still no luck.

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/DataStax Community/apache-cassandra/bin
$  wh="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/DataStax Community/apache-cassandra/bin/"
$ "$wh"nodetool
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused; are you are trying to run a windows program in cygwin or a cygwin program that needs access to your windows tool?